# What is logical consequence and logically equivalent in discrete math?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I'm having a difficult time understanding what the meaning are with these two.

Is it correct if I have (P ⇒ Q) ∧ P and I say Q is a logical consequence. This means that whatever P may be T or F the result all comes down to what Q is?

Comment: [Logical consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence#Semantic_consequence) means "every time the *premise* ($(P \to Q) \land P$) is TRUE, also the *conclusion* ($Q$) is TRUE."

Comment: [Logical equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence) means that the two formulas have the same truth value in every model.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Can you maybe give an example of logically equivalent? Thats the last thing I'm not so sure about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Logical consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence#Semantic_consequence) means :

> "every time the premise ($(P → Q) ∧ P$) is TRUE, also the conclusion ($Q$) is TRUE."

[Logical equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence) means that the two formulas have the same truth value in every model.

$Q$ is a *logical consequence* of $(P → Q) ∧ P$ but the two are **not** logically equivalent.

An example of two logically equivalent formulas is : $(P → Q)$ and $(¬P ∨ Q)$. We can use a [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_equality) to check it.

For details, see [Logical consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence) :

> "is a fundamental concept in logic, which describes the *relationship between statements* that hold true when one statement logically follows from one or more statements. A valid logical argument is one in which the conclusion is the consequence of the premises."

A [premise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premise) is a statement that an argument claims will induce or justify a conclusion. In other words, a premise is an assumption that something is true.

A *conclusion* is the statement justified (in mathematics and logic : proved) by the premises of the argument.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to MSE.

You refer to the modus ponens, a logical rule. Semantically, it says that if $P$ is true and $P\Rightarrow Q$ is true, then $Q$ is true.

The rule is also (equivalently) applied in proofs (syntax). If you can write down $P$ and $P\Rightarrow Q$ starting from the axioms and the hypothetical propositions, then you can write down $Q$.